Docker Swarm: Forward requests only to containers on the same host as swarm load balancer
I really like the ergonomics of the docker stack deploy to get the simplicity of having zero downtime deployment with update_config > order > start-first. However, the behavior of such setup is that the service will forward requests to containers in any host connected to the ingress network. From their docs, this is the mechanism:

I have read the docs quite extensively and cannot find any clue to answer this question: is it possible to only forward the request to the container running on the same host as the swarm load balancer? I want this because the hosts are already behind a webserver/load balancer (Caddy) with a healthcheck and doesn't need to load balance again since it will add additional (unnecessary) latency.

Docker swarm load balancing is done on two levels: There is an ingress load balancer that handles traffic incoming to the swarm, and a virtual IP load balancer that handles service to service traffic.
Both can be bypassed:
If you have your own ingress load balancer, deploy replicas onto each ingress node that is receiving external traffic and use "host" mode on the published port.
e.g.
service:
  ingress:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
    - publish: 80
      target: 8080
      mode: host

Next, docker creates a virtual ip based load balancer for all services with the service name as the dns alias. If you have a service called "web" then "web" resolves to this VIP. Docker swarm also registers a dns alias tasks.{service-name} which is a DNSRR with an A record directly to each service container. Traefik and Caddy should automatically use the individual task IPs directly, other proxies that support DNSRR as service discovery should be configured with e.g. http://tasks.web:8080 and will bypass dockers own load balancer.
